# Issue with file redirection and coding in c++ using ubuntu linux

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to complete an assignment where I create a numbers.txt file that has one line with six numbers without any addition or subtraction. I have to write a program(sum.cpp) that adds the numbers using cin as an input. I have instructions to go to linux and type in $./sum < numbers.txt and it should print sum.

I tried doing that and multiple variations of the code and got a blank screen. When I did it in another compiler I got 32764 which is way off from the sum.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int sum = 0;
  int input= 0;
  while(cin>>input)
       {
         sum+=input;
       }

  cout << sum << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Expected Results :

If you have a file numbers.txt that contains:

```
10 15 16 -7 102 345
```

then if you redirect it into the program, it should report:

```
$ ./sum < numbers.txt
481
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce - the above code outputs 481 for me. You probably don't have numbers.txt in your current working directory, or it doesn't contain the text you expect it to

Comment: This code works fine for me.  How are you compiling and running it?

Comment: g++ sum.cpp, run the line , I also tried just running the first line. When I write ls both numbers.txt and sum.cpp is availble in my directory

Comment: `g++ sum.cpp -o sum` then `./sum < numbers.txt`

Comment: @NeilButterworth that worked, could you please explain why and what I did wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try running the following commands, after placing both `sum.cpp` and `numbers.txt` in the same directory

`g++ sum.cpp -o sum.out`

`chmod +x ./sum.out`

`./sum.out < numbers.txt`